# Numeric solve with scipy

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, solver

I have some experience programming with Python, but not in scientific applications. I know that scipy provides a function `fsolve (func, initial_guess)` for numerically solving equations. However, I don't know how to implement it with my equation. Using the TI CAS software, it would look like that, whereas of course "0.196" is a changing value:
[image: nSolve(1/3tan(100/73.85t)+1/3t^(2)-1/10t=0.196,t)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html) it seems fairly straightforward, just rearrange the equation to the expected format `func(x) = 0` first.

[image]

[image]

```
1/3.0*np.tan(100/73.85*t)+1/3.0*pow(t,2)-1/10.0*t - 0.196
```

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np

def func(t,k):
    return 1/3.0*np.tan(100/73.85*t)+1/3.0*pow(t,2)-1/10.0*t - k

k = 0.196
root = fsolve(func, 1, args=(k))
print(root)

# [0.37653542]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was exactly what I was looking for. I didn't knew that you had to rearrange the equation first, since every other program I tried did it automatically. Well.. maybe I should read the documentation more carefully.